# Can a string ever get shorter when converted to upper/lowercase?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode

A string may get longer (in terms of Unicode codepoints) when converted to upper or lower case. For example, `'ß'.upper()` evaluates to `'SS'`. But are there strings that get shorter? That is, does there exist a string `s` such that the expression

```
len(s.lower()) < len(s) or len(s.upper()) < len(s)
```

evaluates to `True`?

Comment: You'll need to create a loop to find that out. Just try the following expression for each Unicode character and then set the expression value for each iteration to a boolean..

Comment: @geekpradd there is 1.1 million unicode chharacters, so that is 10^12 possible 2-chars combinations: it will take quite a while to test them all.

Comment: May I ask why you want to know this? For what implementation do you need this? Or do you just want to score reputation points? There are indeed many unicode characters but it makes only sense to `.upper` or `.lower` them for a small fraction of them.

Comment: I know but hey that's the only way to find the answer to this illogical question.  I don't think anyone knows the answer to this (not even the unicode devs sincs the work was distributed). And 1.1 million iterations may not necessarily take that long  depending on the algorithm.

Comment: If you're trying all two-element combinations of each of the 1.1 million unicode characters, that's one million _squared_ iterations, or about a trillion.

Comment: @geekpradd, looping over all Unicode characters will answer the question for all strings that consist of a single character. That is not the same thing as answering it for all strings.

Comment: @kasper Taeymans, I don't care about reputation points. I am interested in the question for its own sake, but it was prompted by a practical problem (given that I know that a.startswith(b), but testing case-insensitively, what part of a should I remove so that what is removed is equivalent to b?)

Comment: Sorry for being an ass.  I've never liked unicode parsing.  In Python, unicode is a mess (both 2 and 3). Languages like Go have nailed unicode by having every thing from the source to the output in unicode which isn't true for Python.

Comment: Perhaps I ought to just ask my more complicated question directly, rather than risk exhibiting the x/y problem.

Comment: If you need this for comparison purposes you might look at pythons 3.x string method `casefold()`

Comment: There is an uppercase I with a dot (used e.g. in Turkey). If that is represented as two codepoints (capital I and combining dot above), lowercasing this may give you just a single codepoint. I haven't tried this and it's just a wild guess that doesn't seem clearly contradictory to me, so please double-check this before believing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may be implementation dependent. I'll answer based on the CPython source.

It seems to me that there are two possible situations where calling `lower` on a string can make it shorter.

1. Some combination of two Unicode points next to one another get converted into one Unicode point.
2. A single Unicode point gets converted into an empty string.

We can determine whether case 1 is possible by examining the type signature of the internal lowercase conversion function. Here it is in [Objects/unicodectype.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/88a99ea8a4cf/Objects/unicodectype.c).

```
int _PyUnicode_ToLowerFull(Py_UCS4 ch, Py_UCS4 *res)
{
    const _PyUnicode_TypeRecord *ctype = gettyperecord(ch);

    if (ctype->flags & EXTENDED_CASE_MASK) {
        int index = ctype->lower & 0xFFFF;
        int n = ctype->lower >> 24;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            res[i] = _PyUnicode_ExtendedCase[index + i];
        return n;
    }
    res[0] = ch + ctype->lower;
    return 1;
}
```

I don't 100% understand this code, but I observe that the first parameter `ch` is a single Unicode point. Since it operates only on individual characters and not character combinations, it seems like case 1 is ruled out; combinations of code points won't get turned into a smaller sequence.

With that out of the way, we can determine whether case 2 ever occurs by just iterating up to `sys.maxunicode` and seeing if any single value has a length of zero after lowering.

```
>>> import sys
>>> unicode_chars = list(map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode+1)))
>>> [x for x in unicode_chars if len(x.lower()) == 0]
[]
```

Looks like case 2 is also busted.

We can apply the above logic to `upper` as well. For case 1, the implementation for `_PyUnicode_ToUpperFull` is nearly identical to its lower counterpart; and for case 2, the corresponding list comprehension likewise returns an empty list.

## Conclusion

Nope, `lower` and `upper` never make anything shorter.

Comment: Incidentally, `lower` can make a string _longer_. In particular, `U+0130 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE` becomes a regular ascii 'i' plus `U+0307 COMBINING DOT ABOVE`.

Comment: I should also point out that it does look like `_PyUnicode_ToLowerFull` is _capable_ of returning a zero-length string, it just never appears to do so for my particular locale. Python distributions whose `unicodetype_db.h` file is different may have a different result. So... Yeah. Reiterating "implementation dependent".

Comment: There are also locale conventions. In France, the uppercase of _éclair_ is conventionally _ECLAIR_ which will be a shorter string if you used the NFD normal form for the lowercase version.